# I can't view offline clan member's profile

Tags: starcraft-2

When I try to look at a clan members profile, I get this error message, even though the entire clan are from the EU servers.

It's nice to watch how your fellow clan members are progressing towards the next league. Especially those you spar and practice with. I don't get this message with all members, but a lot of them.

[image]

**What is causing this error message, and is there a way to get around this message - so I can view my clan members profile when they are offline?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this happens when you try to inspect someone who is not in your Friends list and is currently offline. Being clanmates is not enough.

You should be able to view their profile when they are online, though.

Comment: This is solved by adding a player to your friendslist. Which is odd since it says player does not a profile on your realm ish... :)